Hidden Markov with both discrete and continuous states
Is there a formalism for a Hidden Markov model that is :

time-discrete
with both discrete and continuous states
with continuous (gaussian linear) observation (of the continuous space)
?


For specifics, here is a more detailed view of the problem :
Let there be a (discrete-time) system that can be described with a $n$-multidimensional state $X$.
Let the first $n_d$ dimensions of the state be inherently discrete (and in a finite number). Let $X^d$ be the corresponding $n_d$-dimensional state.
Let the following $n_c$ dimensions of the state (such that $n_d+n_c=n$) be inherently continuous. Let $X^c$ be the corresponding $n_c$-dimensional state. Let us consider that $X^c$ can be be adequately represented with a $n_c$ dimensional gaussian pdf at each time step.
($X$ is thus the simple concatenation of $X^d$ and $X^c$.)
Say we know, for any current $n$-dimensional state $X_k$ at step $k$ :

calculate / provide the a priori discrete probabilities of $X^d_{k+1}$. These probabilities are dependant of the full $X_k$ (both discrete and continuous states).
calculate / provide the a priori multimodal gaussian probabilities of $X^c_{k+1}$. Same thing here : these probabilities are dependant of the full $X_k$ (both discrete and continuous states). Note that, for any given $X^d_{k+1}$, $X^c_{k+1}$ can be considered gaussian, but $X^c_{k+1|k}$ is inherently multi-modal (one mode for each possible $X^d_{k+1}$).

Note the problem is indeed Markovian : the a priori pdf of $X_{k+1}$ is only dependent on $X_{k}$ and nothing else.
If it helps, for simplicity, we can consider here that the continuous states $X^c_k$ are sufficiently well-known that their uncertainty does not matter in this "propagation" step. The a priori pdf of $X_{k+1}$ (both $X^d_{k+1}$ and $X^c_{k+1}$) do depend a lot on $X^c_k$, but not in a meaningful way with respect to the uncertainty on $X^c_k$.
Now, at each time step, let us have a gaussian linear $Z=HX^c$ observation of $X^c$, with $H$ an observation matrix. We also know $R$ the local error covariance of this observation.
Let us also consider that all $X^c$ states are observable, and, if it helps, we can further consider that
I would like, a t each time step, to be able to compute the most likely sequence of discrete events $X^d$ from say the last $p+1$ steps (so the current one and the previous $p$ ones).
Is there a formalism for such a Hidden Markov model ?

time-discrete
with both discrete and continuous states
with continuous (gaussian linear) observation (of the continuous space)
?


[And finally, for reference, here is what I have considered :

I can look at a Gaussian Hidden Markov Model (GHMM).

I can subdivide the $X^c$ continuous state-space into enough (well-chosen) subspaces and expand $X^d$ as required, such that the probabilities of $X^d_{k+1}$ can be considered fully determined by $X^d_k$. Then I guess it is a standard approach of GHMM and applying a Viterbi algorithm (I say standard but I have never done so).
My issue is that said subdivision of the continuous state-space would not necessarily be trivial (in my case anyway), and would (obviously) lead to a significant increase in number of states (or require some smart gymnastics to only restict the algorithms to a subset of the extended discrete states).

I can look at a Gaussian Mixture Model approach (GMM) (with transition matrix between modes).

Each Kalman filter would make one and only assumption regarding $X^d$. The state of each KF would be $X^c$. Only the propagation step would differ from one KF to the next, based on the corresponding assumption regading $X^d$.
Noting that I have a transition matrix from $X^d_k$ to $X^d_{k+1}$ at each time step (calculated from $X^c{k}$ but considered independant from it), I know with simple maximum likelihood approach, how to get the most likely state $X^d$ at each timestep.
My issues are twofold :

This doesn't provide me corrected ("smoothed") past estimates. I have read about the Viterbi algorithm (once again, never used it before), but I'm unsure if I can apply it here, mainly due to my second point :

My main gripe is that there is the underlying issue of each KF filter being only consistent with a constant discrete hypothesis. None of them would be consistent with a discrete state transition. This feels unacceptable in my use case (transitions are a critical aspect of the system and I do need to compute the most likely sequence of discrete states).



I can look at a Gaussian Mixture Hidden Markov Model.

Here the idea would be, as with the original GHMM, to subdivide the $X^c$ continuous state-space the same way, but consider them gaussian modes instead of expanding $X^d$.
I'm unsure if it can correctly account for mode switching inside a given discrete state (I would guess it's not supposed to), in which case it's obviously more flawed than what I could achieve with the initial GHMM (with expanded discrete states)

What would be ideal

All in all, the main issue is that the original problem, while indeed Markovian (the a priori pdf of $X_{k+1}$ is only dependent on $X_{k}$), mixes both discrete and continuous states, and all these previous designs have in consequence been trying to deal with the discrete and continuous states separately.]

I don't have a full answer but not enough reputation to post a comment. It seems that the problem is quite different depending on whether $X^c$ is observable or not.

If $X^c$ is observed, then I think it is more helpful to think about it as being part of the observation process rather than part of the hidden state process. Then, you have a hidden Markov model (HMM) with only discrete states $X^d$. A few comments about this:

You describe a multivariate hidden state $X^d$, but could this be reduced to a univariate hidden state with larger state space? This would help formulate the model as a "standard" HMM.

If the distribution of $X^d_{t+1}$ depends on $X^d_t$ and $X^c_t$, then you might need to include a feedback mechanism, i.e., the hidden state at time $t+1$ must depend on the observation at time $t$. The standard HMM algorithms can still be used, and an example of this is described for example by Zucchini et al. (2008). Modeling time series of animal behavior by means of a latent-state model with feedback. Biometrics, 64(3), 807-815.

If the distribution of $X^c_{t+1}$ depends on $X^c_{t}$, and if you treat $X^c$ as an observed variable, then this can be implemented with an autoregressive HMM. That is, the distribution of the observation at time $t+1$ doesn't just depend on the state at time $t+1$, but also on the observation at time $t$. Again, this doesn't preclude from using the standard HMM algorithms with minor modifications, and this is for example mentioned in Section 10.4 of Zucchini et al. (2017). Hidden Markov Models for Time Series: An Introduction Using R, 2dn Edition.

The state-dependent observation probabilities/densities for this model would be a little complicated to compute, because they would involve the distribution of $Z_t$ given $X^c_t$ and the distribution of $X^c_t$ given $X^d_t$ and $X^c_{t-1}$, or something like this. But in principle it should be possible.



If $X^c$ is not observed, then this sounds like a more complex problem. I don't know much about this topic, but there are Markov-switching versions of the Kalman filter which should be able to deal with both discrete and continuous latent states jointly. For example:

Kim (1994). Dynamic linear models with Markov-switching. Journal of Econometrics, 60(1-2), 1-22. (I think this is the seminar paper, and the approach is sometimes called the "Kim filter".)
Hamaker & Grasman (2012). Regime switching state-space models applied to psychological processes: Handling missing data and making inferences. Psychometrika, 77, 400-422. (This seems like a more accessible paper on the topic.)



